# Photocurable Polymer with no oxygen functional group or whose the structure is well known

Tags: polymers, photochemistry

I'm experimenting with the PDMS. I want to change the material with no oxygen containing functional group.

Is there a UV curable polymer with no oxygen atom?
Preferably cheap.

Or

Please recommend any UV curable or photoresist with well-known morphological property and molecular (polymer) structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this addresses all your criteria,  but acrylonitrile is polymerisable by light and is oxygen free.

Comment: I will google it and check if it can be used in my system. Thanks.